# Criteria for system of parameters in polynomial rings 

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $k$ be a field and let $R=k[x_1,...,x_n]$ be a polynomial ring over $k$. A subset $\lbrace y_1,...,y_n\rbrace$ of $R$ is called a homogenous system of parameters (hsop) of $R$, if

- the $y_i$ are homogenous polynomials
- $R$ is finitely generated as $k[y_1,...,y_n]$-module

I am looking for criteria, when $\lbrace y_1,...,y_n\rbrace \subseteq R$ is a hsop of $R$.

In the paper [(link)](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-03/S0002-9939-96-02955-3/S0002-9939-96-02955-3.pdf) the authors say there is a classical criterion given by the resultant and refer to chapter I of a book [(link)](http://ia600307.us.archive.org/34/items/algebraictheoryo00macauoft/algebraictheoryo00macauoft.pdf) of Macaulay. Unfortunately I'm not able to figure out what the criterion might be.

Can anyone provide me that criterion or knows alternative criteria ? Any hint is appreciated.

**Edit:** I want to add that the following turned out to be helpful for working with hsop's over finite fields:

- Hailong's criterion: $\lbrace y_1, ..., y_n \rbrace$ is a hsop $\Leftrightarrow$ 
  $0$ is the only common root of $y_1,...,y_n$ in the algebraic closure of $k$
- Inspecting the proof of Proposition 11.13 in Atiyah-MacDonald's book on commuative 
  algebra shows that a hsop can be obtained in the following way:

  Choose any $y_1 \neq 0$ and if $y_1,...,y_i$ are found, $y_{i+1} \in R$ can be taken to be any polynomial not contained in the minimal primes of $(y_1,...,y_i)$.

For example, I wanted to prove that for a hsop of $\mathbb{F}_p[x_1,...x_n]$ the polynomial functions of the $y_i$ are non-zero. But since $y_1 \neq 0$ can be any polynomial, using Hailong's criterion, it's easy to see that 
$$y_1 = x^py-xy^p, y_2= x^m + y^m \in \mathbb{F}_p[x,y]\quad m=\frac{p+1}{2}$$
is a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the resultant $Res(g_1,\cdots, g_n)$ of $n$ (not necessarily homogenous) polynomials in $n-1$ variables is $0$ if and only if the $g_i$s have a common root.

Now, the $y_1,\cdots, y_n$ form an sop iff $(0,\cdots, 0)$ is the only common root. But if they have another common root, then because of homogeniety they must have a root with $x_i=1$ for some $i$. That observation leads to the following criterion:

Let $g_{ij}$ be the polynomial $y_i|_{x_j=1}$ and $R_j = Res(g_{1j}, \cdots, g_{nj})$. Then the $y_i$s form an sop iff $R_1R_2...R_n \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In particular your first criterion was really helpful. 

Answer (score 1):

See the introduction of the following paper for an answer

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2011-139-08/S0002-9939-2011-10790-1/home.html

It cited the paper
G. Scheja, U. Storch, Uwe Differentielle Eigenschaften der Lokalisierungen analytischer Algebren, Math. Ann. 197 (1972), 137–170.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the criteria. The paper can also be found 
on the arxiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3046v1. The advantage of 
this paper is that the criterion is well-readable, while in the 
Scheja-Storch paper it's difficult to make out. 